# Uploaded app to google play store, can't open it

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I uploaded my APK file to the Google Play store. It's published, and I can now find it in the Google Play store. I installed it, and it said:"installed" after. How ever, there is no "Open" button available, and the app isn't with the rest of my apps. I can't find it.

Does anyone know why this is and how i can fix it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.informatie.rodekruis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAINACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BezoekActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bezoek" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BEZOEKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AfspraakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_afspraak" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AFSPRAAKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.CONTACTACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MeningActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mening" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MENINGACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.RouteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ROUTEACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SpecialistenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specialisten" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SPECIALISTENACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bwc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AgendaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AGENDAACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informatie" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.INFOACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vriend" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VRIENDACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FoldersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folders" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FOLDERSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NieuwsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuws">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NIEUWSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your intent filter declaration i.e., action and category tags are incorrect. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First verify you have it installed on your phone for real. On most phones, it can be checked by reviewing list of installed apps at **Settings** > **Applications**.

If yes, then you may not have a launch-able activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Verify you have an activity with an intent filter similar to what shown below:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yeah but the action and category values are incorrect and its the reason there's no icon in the launcher.

Comment: So what I need to change is the "MAIN" and the "LAUNCHER" ?

Comment: Exactly those. Also after changing and rebuilding, I recommend you sideload the APK on your phone and verify things are working as expected as it will be faster to find and fix things in case.

Comment: Make sure to completely replace the category value, no just the LAUNCHER.

Comment: Do i need to put MAIN and LAUNCHER on all the actions, also below the main one? or DEFAULT and LAUNCHER ? or just change the main one?

Comment: You need to set both, action and category correctly on all the activity declarations.

Comment: If it worked for you, don't forget to accept it as an answer.