# Uploaded an Application to the play store but it won't open

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

So I recently uploaded my Android application to the Google Play store and it published successfully. This is the application here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kyoudai.sudioku

The problem is, when anyone installs thiis application, they cannot open it i.e. the open option does not appear on the playstore, only the uninstall option. This application also cannot be found in the application drawer on any device, or in the list of installed applications. I've tried editing my manifest and included everything necessary but I have no idea why this happens. I generally believe if there was an issue with my code that should not be possible for an android application, the play store would flag it. When I was developing this, it showed up on the emulator application drawer so I assumed it was fine. I'm not sure why this happens, and I'm not even sure where to contact google regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

Given people are gonna jump on the manifest configuration, here it is: https://github.com/BerserkerLan/Sudoku-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Post manifest configurations

Comment: Did you try to generate apk and install manually on devices? Please, post an error. In other case it looks like an advertisement. :)

Comment: So I've double checked my manifest with another application I've published before and it's almost identitical in what matters so not sure, also I've tested it on emulators directly and it installs and shows on the application drawer on that too

Comment: I'll try to test an APK debug one later today and get back to you on that

Comment: Also on the error, there just isn't any! Google Play essentially just shows no Open option and it isn't on an application drawer, so there's not really any stack trace to share

Comment: Yes, I checked, it installs from Play Market, but cannot be opened, only removed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404488/uploaded-app-to-google-play-store-cant-open-it?

Comment: Oh Thanks for linking that! I'll take a look at that too and get back to this :) Lots to do when I go back home!

Comment: I see you found a solution. Good luck!

Comment: @CoolMind Thank you!

Comment: @eagerProgrammer919, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, the issue was that I just had too many category elements in my intent-filter and thus somehow that was interfering with the MAIN, VIEW and LAUNCHER elements, so now I only have those three in it and it launches fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your build is signed APK/Bundle

Comment: Yes I made sure of that, in fact Google Play rejects any application that isn't so it should have flagged it in that case